# System.Text.Json Serializing dynamic object, won't ignore nulls

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, system.text.json

I need to serialize a `dynamic` to JSON but want to suppress all `null` properties (the actual use case is executing a SQL query with results going into a `dynamic` and having many null columns).

Not having any luck with `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize()`, no matter which `JsonIgnoreCondition` value I use in the options. The `JsonIgnoreCondition` option works fine for actual types, just not on a `dynamic`.

```
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json;

var foo = new Foo();
var fooJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true});
var fooJson1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true, DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault});
var fooJson2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo, new JsonSerializerOptions() {WriteIndented = true, DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull});

Console.WriteLine("fooJson:");
Console.WriteLine(fooJson);
Console.WriteLine("fooJson1:");
Console.WriteLine(fooJson1);
Console.WriteLine("fooJson2:");
Console.WriteLine(fooJson2);

dynamic dynamicFoo = new ExpandoObject();
dynamicFoo.Prop1 = "something";
dynamicFoo.Prop2 = (int?)null;
dynamicFoo.Prop3 = (string)null;

var dynamicFooJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dynamicFoo, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true});
var dynamicFooJson1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dynamicFoo, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true, DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault});
var dynamicFooJson2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dynamicFoo, new JsonSerializerOptions() {WriteIndented = true, DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull});

Console.WriteLine("dynamicFooJson:");
Console.WriteLine(dynamicFooJson);
Console.WriteLine("dynamicFooJson1:");
Console.WriteLine(dynamicFooJson1);
Console.WriteLine("dynamicFooJson2:");
Console.WriteLine(dynamicFooJson2);


public class Foo
{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public int Prop2 {get;set;}
    public int? Prop3 {get;set;}
}
```

Produces the following output

```
fooJson:
{
  "Prop1": null,
  "Prop2": 0,
  "Prop3": null
}
fooJson1:
{}
fooJson2:
{
  "Prop2": 0
}
dynamicFooJson:
{
  "Prop1": "something",
  "Prop2": null,
  "Prop3": null
}
dynamicFooJson1:
{
  "Prop1": "something",
  "Prop2": null,
  "Prop3": null
}
dynamicFooJson2:
{
  "Prop1": "something",
  "Prop2": null,
  "Prop3": null
}
```

Comment: I am going out on a limb here, but as far as i remember, the ExpandoObject is really more of a dictionary (it even implements IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`), with Prop1, Prop2, Prop3 and their values just being key-value-pairs. There should be no Prop1, Prop2, Prop3 properties (in the sense of properties as members of a type) in the ExpandoObject. That would explain the setting for ignoring null/defaults not applying. But it's also possible that i remember wrong, and that i just talked bollocks...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Thanks for the suggestion - that's going to be the thing that saves me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround / solution seems to hinge on the fact that a `dynamic` is really just an `IDictionary<string, object>` (thanks, @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace) - so a custom `JsonConverter` that ignores null values in the dictionary works great.

```
public class DynamicConverter : JsonConverter<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    public override IDictionary<string, object>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IDictionary<string, object> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var val in value)
        {
            if (val.Value != null)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(val.Key);
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, val.Value, options);
            }
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```